# Jquery. how we show a same div for multiple times step by step not once when my condition is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a div with two input fields, i want to show this div again when both fields are filled using jquery.
this same div with both fileds show for next data. this process continuous until condition not false.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').blur(function () {
        var input1 = $("#med").val();
        var input1 = $("#med").val();
        var input2 = $("#pon").val();

        if (input1 != '' && input2 != '') {

            $("medicine_fields").show();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group form-inline" id="medicine_fields">
    <label>Medicine</label>
    <input type="text" list="medicines" id="med" name="medicines" class="form-control" />
    <datalist id="medicines">
        <option value="">--select or write--</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="abc">dec</option>
    </datalist>
    <label style="margin-left:20px">Potency</label>
    <input type="text" list="potency" id="pon" class="form-control" />
    <datalist id="potency">
        <option value="">--select or write--</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>

    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: So, each time you fill those 2 inputs another row with those same 2 inputs should show up below?

Comment: a) you need to use classes, b) you need to clone and append, c) you probably want to use a delegated event if you are going to clone and append, d) you probably want to change your input names to send arrays if you are going to have multiple inputs with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [clone(true)](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function together with [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/). The `true` parameter clones the added functions too. Please note that you cannot use `id=""` in that case because `id` needs to be unique.

```js
$('.med, .pon').blur (function () {

  //get input-values
  var input1 = $(this).parent ().find ('.med').val ();
  var input2 = $(this).parent ().find ('.pon').val ();

  //check if both values not empty
  if (input1 != '' && input2 != '') {
  
    //clone div and reset inputs.
    var new_div = $(this).parent ().clone (true);
        new_div.find ('.med').val ('');
        new_div.find ('.pon').val ('');
  
    //append clone to body
    $('body').append (new_div);
  
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group form-inline medicine_fields">
  <label>Medicine</label>
  <input type="text" list="medicines" name="medicines" class="form-control med" />
  <datalist id="medicines">
    <option value="">--select or write--</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="abc">dec</option>
  </datalist>
  <label style="margin-left:20px">Potency</label>
  <input type="text" list="potency" class="form-control pon" />
  <datalist id="potency">
    <option value="">--select or write--</option>
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: WayneOS please guide me how we validate the last input empty filed not save my database only filled fields value save in database

Comment: @muneeb well its hard to tell if i don't see any code. if you do it with PHP you can check for `if (!empty ($_GET['your_input_name'])`. But you will need to add the `name=""` attribute to your input.

Answer (score 0):

Change the id's of the inputs to `class=""` so you can have multiple of them on the same page. Bind the event listener to the document (or some parent element that will wrap all fields). And use the JavaScript below:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.med, .pon', function(e) {
    var triggerParent = $(this).closest('[id^="medicine_fields"]'),
        input1 = triggerParent.find(".med").val(),
        input2 = triggerParent.find(".pon").val();

    if(input1 != '' && input2 != ''){
        var parent = $(this).parents('form'), // change this to the wrapping element where the new fields should be.
            count = parent.find('[id^="medicine_fields"]').length,
            html = $("#medicine_fields").clone().attr('id', 'medicine_fields_'+(count+1));

        html.find('datalist, input').val(''); // reset values
        parent.append(html);

    }
});
```